# Extend NSTextView or implement NSTextInputClient?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I'm trying to implement a text editing component with certain characteristics and I wonder what is the best route, extend NSTextView or implement NSTextInputClient.

The text component should obviously support UTF-8 and attributed text. I also want to display information balloons when the user hovers on certain words.

How hard is it to implement a new text view from NSTextInputClient? How easy it is to display custom views with a normal NSTextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to change the presentation of the text, and not how it is being stored, subclass NSTextView (the presentation).

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/TextViewTask.html

Comment: Are you confirming or contradicting Fruity Geek?